# Install Intel python 3.8 (Older Release)

Tags: python, linux, intel, intel-oneapi

I need to download 3.8 python shell script in Linux. But I can not find it anywhere. I found the below script which can be downloaded for Linux but it has Intel python 3.8 only.

https://registrationcenter-download.intel.com/akdlm/irc_nas/18720/l_pythoni39_oneapi_p_2022.1.0.214....

Could you please help me get Intel python 3.8 shell script?

Comment: what You need is to install `python 3.8` in linux such that you can run some scripts? I was so confused...The link you provided is broken?...You are saying `Linux` why you tagged `conda`?

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3814/ is supported until 2024-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for Intel python 3.8. Do get that, you can try creating a new conda environment with the below command:

```
conda create -n idp intelpython3_core python=3.8
conda activate idp
```

But if you're only looking for a shell script to install intel python3.8, you need to buy a license. If you don't have one and follow this steps:

1. Access the Registration Center (https://registrationcenter.intel.com/en/products/) and follow the instructions below.
2. Select the product and OS
3. Define the required version & click download.

Please refer [Intel Python Release notes](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/release-notes/distribution-for-python-release-notes.html) for more information!